# How to search using Activerecord in a json field stored as text in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a Json field stored in DB as text.

I want to look for records that contain `Harvard` as a value for those keys

```
json_data['infoOnProgram']['universityName']
```

How should I construct my where request to search on that Json field.

```
Student.where(json_data...
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you studied PostgreSQL's `hstore` data type? It might provide smart SELECT queries into JSON-style data stored in a `text` field.

Comment: The problem I can not change the type of the column. I have to somehow solve that problem without touching the DB...

Answer (score 0):

If there are a not very many records you can do this, which will be very expensive:

```
harvard_students = Student.map {|stud|
  hash = JSON.parse(stud.json_data)
  hash['infoOnProgram']['universityName'] == 'Harvard' ? stud : nil
}.compact
```

if you have lots and lots of records to iterate through you can limit your list with a regex query:

Simple

```
Student.where("json data like '%Harvard%'")
```

slightly better

```
Student.where("json data like '%infoOnProgram%universityName%Harvard%'")
```

The problem is without knowing how the data is structured it is hard to create a specific regex.  You can use the where to limit and the iteration to confirm more precisely that these records are what you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about limiting the records by where and then iterate. The problem is that as you said it will be expensive. That's why I was hoping to find a way in the request itself...

Comment: I tried something like this: `Student.where("json data like '%\"universityName\"\=\>\"Harvard\"%'")`, but it seems it blocks in `=`signe...

Comment: `"universityName"=>"Harvard"` isn't JSON, that's Ruby hash literal syntax. JSON would be `"universityName":"Harvard"` (with possible whitespace around the `:` depending on how the JSON was encoded). You could look into adding a `gin(json_data gin_trgm_ops)` index to speed up pattern matching queries but you'd still need to be careful with your LIKE pattern or regex (to respect what JSON really looks like) and you might not be allowed to add indexes if you can't change column types.

Comment: Yes you should really look closely at the JSON (string data) so you know exactly what your regex is looking for.  You can start with something like Student.where("json_data like '%Harvard%'").limit(10) to look at some examples and build from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure you really do have valid JSON in your text column then you could cast it to `jsonb` (or `json`) and use the usual [JSON operators and functions that PostgreSQL provides](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html):

```
Student.where(
  "json_data::jsonb -> 'infoOnProgram' ->> 'universityName' = ?",
  'Harvard'
)

Student.where(
  'json_data::jsonb -> :info ->> :name = :uni',
  info: 'infoOnProgram',
  name: 'universityName',
  uni:  'Harvard'
)

Student.where(
  'cast(json_data as jsonb) #>> array[:path] = :uni',
  path: %w[infoOnProgram universityName],
  uni: 'Harvard'
)
```

This is going to be an expensive query though as you won't be able to use any indexes. You really should start the process of changing the column's type to `jsonb`, that would validate the JSON, avoid having to type cast in queries, allow indexing, ...